# Submit button of a Google Sheet sidebar not working

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

beginner of Google AppScript here, I've been trying to modify a sidebar from a tutorial ("Create Sidebar Bootstrap Form on Google Sheets" which you can find on Youtube) to create a form for entering personal expenses. After a few modifications, the submit button is suddenly not working and I haven't been able to pinpoint what I did to mess up the button. Would appreciate if you can take a look at the sheet and the AppScript. Feel free to make edits as you see fit. Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PxQWf8fqE77tfZD7kD0AKYmcv753rjnv40AZQZr6TLI/edit#gid=1528222325

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs at the function that the `Submit` element is trying to use:

```
function SubmitRecord(){
  ...
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnBack)
    .withFailureHandler(showError) // <-- here
    .AddRecord(date, description, remarks, payment_method, amount, category, subcategory);

}
```

Just as `.withSuccessHandler()`, `.withFailureHandler()` requires you to specify a function that will run if there is an error at the server side, else you'll get this error in the [console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction):

[image]

You can solve this by adding a `showError(error)` function to your `ExpenseForm.html` file, for example:

```
function showError(error){
     console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
}
```

---

Documentation from Google: [.withFailureHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction)